# An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made only on ios

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, ssl, lets-encrypt

I've an a running React Native app with Ruby On Rails Server as backend and i'm using let'sencrypt for ssl certificate, and the app is working fine on android and ios on WIFI but on ios only on certain carrier i'm getting

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot
>   be made

but on other mobile networks the app is working fine, i've searched a lot for the issue but still have no idea about how can i solve the issue ? i'm thinking that the carrier is blocking the requests but it's working fine on android. any idea about what maybe the cause of the issue?

Comment: I am using Nginx as Web-Server and Unicorn for application server. I have also deployed SSL certificate using LetsEncrypt and I am also facing the issue that some users face the error you mentioned. There is no specific browser or platform of the users which are facing this error.

Comment: I already have these configurations in my configuration file.

Comment: this fixed my issue, hope to find a solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found the solution hope it helps , the issue was in nginx configuration and has been fixed by adding the following code to nginx.config file .

```
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
```